# Delta-complex structure on connected sum of three copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know that the 'boundary word' of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is $aabb^{-1}$.

If I glue three copies of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ together, is this what I get?

[image]

('inside' edges are pointed outwards)

Comment: You meant the wedge sum? The notation $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2$ doesn't look like connected sum for me. By the way, the edge labelling for $\mathbb{R}P^2 $ should be $abab$, not $abab^{-1}$ as in your first picture.

Comment: I meant connected sum but go the notation confused. I'll re-upload the picture now (with correct side identification also)

Comment: Question edited with new picture uploaded

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt are you by any chance a fourth-year undergraduate at Oxford?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt With Neumann? If so, then yeah :)

Comment: Yup :) I'll come and say hello next time then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might know that attaching a copy of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ by using the connected sum is often referred to as *attaching a crosscap*, where a cross cap has boundary $xx$.
So in this case, it looks like we might $xxyyzz$ as the boundary word for a hexagon to construct $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$.
In fact, this is exactly what we get, and it can be shown that this is the same as what we'd get from looking at the dodecagon with boundary word $ababcdcdefef$, which would come from your picture.

I'll update in a bit with a picture or two, if that would help.

Comment: Ok, so we're using Lemma 5.26 from the Topology course to get from $aabb^{-1}$, and then we're just adding crosscaps ($cc, dd$ etc...). We're also using Lemma 5.21 to get them in the same form.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way of thinking about it purely algebraically - that also shows us that the 12-sided polygon gives us exactly the same as the 6-sided polygon, but using the word-removal lemmas and things to help simplify the word